# Why are not appearing all conferences that belong to the clicked category? ( Column not found: 1054 Unknown column)

Tags: php, laravel

I have a list that shows some categories:

```
<ul class="Categories__Menu">
    @foreach($categories->take(6) as $category)
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#" name="category" id="{{$category->id}}" href="#">{{$category->name}}</a>
        </li>
    @endforeach

    <li><a  data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-lg" href="">More <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks in a category is done an ajax reqquest to get the conferences that belong to that clicked category. For example when the user clicks in the category "IT" that has 2 conferences in the database that have the category "IT" instead of appearing 2 conferences in the view in the network tab with "        dd($conferences);" it appears:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.conference_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from conferences where exists (select * from categories where conferences.id = categories.conference_id and category_conference.id = 2))".
```

Route:

```
Route::get('conferences/where/category/{id}','ConferenceController@WhereHasCategory')->name('category.conferences');
```

ConferenceController method:

```
public function WhereHasCategory(Request $request)
    {
        $conferences = Conference::whereHas('categories', function ($categories) use (&$request) {
            $categories->where('category_conference.id',$request->id);
        })->get();

        //dd($conferences);

        return response()->json($conferences);
    }
```

Ajax:

```
$("a[name='category']").on('click', function(){

    var category_id = $(this).attr("id");

    $('.Categories__Menu li').removeClass('ative');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('ative');

    $.ajax({

        url: '{{ route('category.conferences',null) }}/' + category_id,
        type: 'GET',
        success:function(result){
            $('#conferences').empty();
            var newConferences='';
            var placeholder = "{{route('conferences.show', ['id' => '1', 'slug' => 'demo-slug'])}}";
            $.each(result, function(index, conference) {
                var url = placeholder.replace(1, conference.id).replace('demo-slug', conference.slug);

                newConferences += '<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">\n' +
'                        <div class="card box-shaddow">\n' +
'                            <img class="card-img-top" src='+ conference.image +' alt="Card image cap">\n' +
'                            <div class="card-body">\n' +
'                                <p class="font-size-sm"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>  '+conference.start_date+'</p>\n' +
'                                <h5 class="card-title h6 font-weight-bold text-heading-blue">'+conference.name+'</h5>\n' +
'                                <p class="card-text font-size-sm"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> '+conference.place+', '+conference.city+'</p>\n' +
'                            </div>\n' +
'                           <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">\n' +
'                                 <a href="' + url + '" class="btn btn-primary text-white">More</a>' +
                    ' <span class="font-weight-bold font-size-sm text-heading-blue"> </span>\n'+
'                           </div>\n' +
'                    </div></div>';
            });

            $('#conferences').html(newConferenes);

        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error.status)
        }

    });

});
```

For example, in the database there are 5 conferences that have category_id "2". And when the category with id 2 is clicked the result is what is in the question with only one result. The pivot table category_conference has:

```
id conference_id   category_id

1             1                       1
2            7                      2
3            8                      2
4            9                     2
5            10                    2
...
11           16                    2
```

Models:

```
 class Conference extends Model{
         public function categories(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
        }
    }

    class Category extends Model
    {
        public function conferences(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Conference');
        }
    }
```

The       dd(Category::find(1)->conferences) shows:

```
Collection {#269
#items: array:2 [
0 => Conference {#273
#fillable: array:18 [
0 => "name"
...
]
#dates: array:2 [
0 => "start_date"
1 => "end_date"
]
#appends: array:1 [
0 => "price_range"
]
#connection: "mysql"
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:23 [
"id" => 1
"name" => "Conference title test"
...
]
#original: array:25 [
"id" => 1
"name" => "Conference title test"
...
]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dateFormat: null
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: array:1 [
"pivot" => Pivot {#262
+pivotParent: Category {#268
#connection: "mysql"
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:5 [
"id" => 1
"name" => "Category1"
...
]
#original: array:5 [
"id" => 1
"name" => "Category1"
...
]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: array:1 [
"conferences" => Collection {#269}
]
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#fillable: []
#guarded: array:1 [
0 => "*"
]
}
#foreignKey: "category_id"
#relatedKey: "confenrece_id"
#guarded: []
#connection: "mysql"
#table: "category_conference"
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:2 [
"category_id" => 1
"conference_id" => 1
]
#original: array:2 [
"category_id" => 1
"conference_id" => 1
]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: false
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#fillable: []
}
]
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#guarded: array:1 [
0 => "*"
]
}
1 => Conference {#270
#fillable: array:18 [
0 => "name"
1 => "description"
]
#dates: array:2 [
0 => "start_date"
1 => "end_date"
]
#appends: array:1 [
0 => "price_range"
]
#connection: "mysql"
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:23 [
"id" => 2
"name" => "conference test title 2"
...
]
#original: array:25 [
"id" => 2
"name" => "conference test title 2"
...
]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dateFormat: null
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: array:1 [
"pivot" => Pivot {#267
+pivotParent: Category {#268}
#foreignKey: "category_id"
#relatedKey: "conference_id"
#guarded: []
#connection: "mysql"
#table: "category_conference"
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: true
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: array:2 [
"category_id" => 1
"conference_id" => 2
]
#original: array:2 [
"category_id" => 1
"conference_id" => 2
]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: false
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#fillable: []
}
]
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#guarded: array:1 [
0 => "*"
]
}
]
}
```

Comment: What JSON do you get from `conferences/where/category/{id}`?

Comment: why you are using `whereHas` why not `RouteModel` bind the `category` and then `eager load` the relation

Comment: Thanks, how to check that JSON? The $conferences returns "[{id: 7, name: "Conference test", description: "", start_date: "2018-03-08 06:30:00",…}]
0
:
{id: 7, name: "Conference test", description: "", start_date: "2018-03-08 06:30:00",…}" as it is in the question.

Comment: Can you explain how that RouteModel bind is? Its a many to many relationship a conference can have many categories a category can belong to many categories.

Comment: The "dd($conferences); shows
 ""SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.conference_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from conferences where exists (select * from categories where conferences.id = categories.conference_id and category_conference.id = 2))".".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the conferences from the category:

```
$conferences = Category::find($request->id)->conferences;
```

As Farrukh Ayyaz suggested, [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding) is more elegant:

```
Route::get('conferences/where/category/{category}', ...

public function WhereHasCategory(Category $category)
{
    return response()->json($category->conferences);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is not working. The dd($request->id); shows "1", the id of the clicked category. But dd($conferences) shows "null". Do you know why?

Comment: The category with id "1" has 2 conferences associated.

Comment: It appears "Collection {#269
  #items: array:2 [...".

Comment: So it works. Do you overwrite the value `$conferences` after that?

Comment: The code is just: public function WhereHasCategory(Request $request)
    {
        $conferences = Conference::find($request->id)->conferences;
        return response()->json($conferences);
    }.

Comment: Why are you using `$events`?

Comment: It was a typo. I udpate the question with more details of the Category::find(1)->conferences.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171357/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-johnw).